# solr suggester not working for large data

Tags: solr, timeout, solrcloud

I have solrcloud setup with 110 million documents on 8 nodes. I am trying to build suggestion dictionary on document id.

Following is the configuration i am using in solrconfig.xml

```
<searchComponent name="suggestdocid" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">suggestdocid</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="storeDir">suggester_fuzzy_dir</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">docid</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">lower_string</str>
      <str name="payloadField">title</str>
      <str name="weightField">docid</str>
      <str name="exactMatchFirst">true</str>
      <str name="nonFuzzyPrefix">3</str>
      <str name="preserveSep">false</str>
      <str name="maxEdits">0</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    </lst>
</searchComponent>

<requestHandler name="/suggestdocid" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy" >
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">suggestdocid</str>
      <bool name="distrib">true</bool>
      <str name="shards.qt">/suggestdocid</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggestdocid</str>
    </arr>
</requestHandler>
```

**Note:** I am using payload here because i want to display docid followed by it's respective title whenever user is searching for a docid.

When i am trying to build this dictionary, it is throwing the following error.

org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occured while waiting response from server at: http://server2:8983/solr/doccollection_shard7_replica1 at org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchHandler.handleRequestBody(SearchHandler.java:416) at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:173) at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2477) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:723) at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:529) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:361) at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:305) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1691) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:582) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1180) at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:512) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1112) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) at org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:534) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:320) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServerException: Timeout occured while waiting response from server at: http://server2:8983/solr/doccollection_shard7_replica1  at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:621) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:279) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:268) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219) at org.apache.solr.handler.component.HttpShardHandler.lambda$submit$0(HttpShardHandler.java:163) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at com.codahale.metrics.InstrumentedExecutorService$InstrumentedRunnable.run(InstrumentedExecutorService.java:176) at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ... 1 more Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160) at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84) at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57) at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:261) at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251) at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.receiveResponseHeader(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:197) at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:272) at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:124) at org.apache.solr.util.stats.InstrumentedHttpRequestExecutor.execute(InstrumentedHttpRequestExecutor.java:114) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685) at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487) at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82) at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:515) ... 12 more

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you please reformat exception in a normal format (multiple lines), it's hard to read what's the error

Comment: @Mysterion : Sorry for that. I have updated the format.